# Image name is not showing if image file is not empty codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

Hi I am new to codeigniter. I have a register form with validation.
if form fields are empty the required fields are showing, if the image is not empty and other fields are empty if i submitted the form image name goes away and shows empty.

Here i want to show the image name is if the image is not empty and other fields are empty if the form is  submmitted

Here is my form view

```
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo set_value("name"); ?>">


        <?php echo form_error('name'); ?>

        <label for="">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value("name"); ?>">

            <?php echo form_error('email'); ?>


        <label for="">Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value("password"); ?>">

            <?php echo form_error('password'); ?>


        <label for="">Mobile</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" value="<?php echo set_value("mobile"); ?>">

                <?php echo form_error('mobile'); ?>


        <input type="file" name="image" value="<?php echo set_value('image'); ?>">

                <?php echo form_error('image'); ?>
        <label for=""></label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
```

here is my controller

```
public function index()
{
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', "Name", 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', "Email", 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', "Password", 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', "Mobile", 'required');
  if (empty($_FILES['image']['name']))
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'Document', 'required');
  }
  if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE) {
    $this->load->view('register');

  }
  else{
    $this->store();
  }
}
```

Can any help how to solve this problem

Comment: @vimal S. can you please explain why i want to use store here

Comment: @jvk-What i mean is in your code you are calling a function **store()** if the image is not empty.

Comment: as i know  you can't add file value `<input type="file" name="image" value="<?php echo set_value('image'); ?>"` cz its actual uploaded file. So overcome this issue you can set image label on top of input tag and show uploaded file name. Else no Options...

Comment: if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']))
is your answer?